# VB.net copy object (dataview)

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have been trying to create a copy of an object but it appears to be linked in some way.  Here is an example

```
Dim dataview as DataView = results.DefaultView

' Some amazing foreach loop
' but thoughtout the loop I want to create a copy of the data and then filter it

Dim filterView as DataView = dataview
filterView.RowFilter = "County = '" & loop.County &"'"
```

The plan is to then loop through this subset of data but when I debug the project the data contained within dataview is the same as filterView.  I have tried DirectCast() and still get the same result.  How do I create a copy of the object without creating some link to the original object?

Hope this makes sense but let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Clone method to copy the table structure (Schema).
Use the ImportRow method to copy from table to its clone.
OR
You can use the Copy method of a DataTable object to copy the entire DataTable: 
OR
Copy from the results of a DataView.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308909

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using .Copy() as I couldn't be bothered to copy the data in!